# view with all possible combinations between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a view between two tables, basically with the id's and all the possible combinations between them without repeat. The tables and the data:

```
CREATE TABLE `ta` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `ta` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'ta1');
INSERT INTO `ta` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'ta2');
INSERT INTO `ta` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'ta3');
INSERT INTO `ta` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'ta4');


CREATE TABLE `tb` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `tb` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'tb1');
INSERT INTO `tb` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'tb2');
```

results I want in the view:

```
view_rel_TAXTB
id_a,id_b
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
1,2
2,2
3,2
4,2
```

Comment: A CROSS JOIN? - `SELECT ta.id AS id_a, tb.id AS id_b FROM ta CROSS JOIN tb`

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` clause. You'll get a result set with every row in table A joined to every row in table B.

Comment: Hey @AgRizzo, did you know there's a huge box for answers below the comments section? Just saying.

Comment: @AgRizzo the CROSS JOIN approach made it, yes. Many thanks, I was stuck with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is your query !**

```
 mysql> select a.id as id_a,b.id as id_b from ta a
        -> cross join tb b;
    +------+------+
    | id_a | id_b |
    +------+------+
    |    1 |    1 |
    |    1 |    2 |
    |    2 |    1 |
    |    2 |    2 |
    |    3 |    1 |
    |    3 |    2 |
    |    4 |    1 |
    |    4 |    2 |
    +------+------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```